# Select all elements until - XPath

Tags: php, css, xpath

```
<ul id="ListView">
  <li id="item3d1f07bb0e" class="result clearfix li"></li>
  <li id="item2370583f1f" class="result clearfix li"></li>
  <li id="item43f35da923" class="result clearfix li"></li>
  <li id="item4190e6d48f" class="result clearfix li"></li>
  <li class="result clearfix li"></li>
  <li id="item3ab7e686fe" class="result clearfix li"></li>
</ul>
```

XPath:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'result') and @id]
```

.. grabs all items, but I want it to **stop looking** after it finds a `li` without an `id`.

Comment: Do you want just the 5th element, or do you want the first five elements?

Comment: @OlafDietsche first 4, stop at 5th, ignore all others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//li[contains(@class, 'result') and @id and not(preceding-sibling::li[not(@id)])]
```

stop when the `li` has a preceding sibling `li` without an `id` attribute.

returns:

```
<li id="item3d1f07bb0e" class="result clearfix li"></li>
<li id="item2370583f1f" class="result clearfix li"></li>
<li id="item43f35da923" class="result clearfix li"></li>
<li id="item4190e6d48f" class="result clearfix li"></li>
```